# PayPal Pay Later Messaging when country is unknown?

Tags: paypal

PayPal [Pay Later Messaging Center FAQs](https://www.paypal.com/ppcredit/messaging/faqs) say:

> You are eligible to promote Pay Later offers if you are a US-based merchant with a US-facing website, and a one-time payment integration.

I'm a US-based merchant with an unrestricted global website (~50% international customers). I'd like to have the Pay Later messaging on my pricing page, where it can drive conversions, but I don't know the customer's country at that time. Does the Pay Later dynamic messaging script check the client ipaddress, so I can have the messaging on my pricing page? I know the customer's country during checkout, but that's too late to drive conversions. (I won't know an order price on the pricing page... it could range from around $75 to thousands of dollars.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the Pay Later dynamic messaging script check the client ipaddress, so I can have the messaging on my pricing page?

Yes, it does.